# Player Appears, but Video Doesn't Play

Tags: html, video, wmv

My video player shows, but when I click play it acts as if it is loading the video, stops, but doesn't play.

```
 <object width="100%" height="100%"
type="video/x-ms-asf" url="videos/agent_orange.wmv" data="videos/agent_orange.wmv"
classid="CLSID:6BF52A52-394A-11d3-B153-00C04F79FAA6">
<param name="url" value="videos/agent_orange.wmv">
 <param name="filename" value="videos/agent_orange.wmv">
<param name="autostart" value="1">
 <param name="uiMode" value="full">
<param name="autosize" value="1">
<param name="playcount" value="1"> 
<embed type="application/x-mplayer2" src="videos/agent_orange.wmv" width="100%" height="100%" autostart="true" showcontrols="true" pluginspage="http://www.microsoft.com/Windows/MediaPlayer/"></embed>
</object>
```

This came from a tutorial from [here](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_object.asp).

Comment: What have you tried? Also is this in every browser or just one? Does the video play when clicking on it in the folder? Is everything or nothing hosted at the minute?

Comment: It plays when I click on the video in the folder, but not in the webpage

Answer (score 0):

Video embedding is not natively supported in HTML 4. Media playback highly relies on the available media plug-ins so compatibility is a big issue.

In order for WMV to work on most browsers the user must have the correct plugin installed.

The best solution would be to use multiple video formats as fallback solutions. I would highly recommend looking at HTML 5 and the multimeda elements you can use are much more advanced than the ones in HTML 4. Using the Video element in HTML 5 would allow you to use:

MP4 = MPEG 4 files with H264 video codec and AAC audio codec
WebM = WebM files with VP8 video codec and Vorbis audio codec
Ogg = Ogg files with Theora video codec and Vorbis audio codec

If you had all of these video formats as fall backs then it would work in most browser (ie 9+)

`<video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
  <source src="movie.WebM" type="video/WebM">
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>`

Comment: I would recommend using Firefox and Chrome as well as IE simultaneously when developing any web application as the least in order to see any compatibility problems between the browsers.

Answer (score 0):

```
var player = $("object")[0];
player.controls.play();
```